Gitea redirection to login page does't work with Traefik reverse proxy
I use Traefik as a reverse proxy and gitea as a git server. I configure my gitea container as described here. It works fine, I can open gitea service with gitea path prefix, clone the repository, etc. The problem started when I tried to push my first commit. After executing git push -u origin main command it tries to redirect me to the login page http://{Host}/login/oauth/authorize instead http://{Host}/gitea/login/oauth/authorize. It will work if I add gitea prefix manually, but I want to fix it.

My docker-compos.yml file:
...
services:
  traefik:
    image: docker://traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    networks:
      - network
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:z"

  gitea:
    image: docker://gitea/gitea:latest
    container_name: gitea
    environment:
      - USER_UID=1000
      - USER_GID=1000
    volumes:
      - ~/gitea:/data
      - ~/gitea/config:/data/gitea/conf
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitea.rule=PathPrefix(`/gitea`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.gitea.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.gitea-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/gitea"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gitea.middlewares=gitea-stripprefix"
    ports:
      - "10880:3000"
      - "10022:22"
    networks:
      - network
    depends_on:
      - mysql


My gitea configuration file
RUN_USER = git
WORK_PATH = /data/gitea
RUN_MODE = prod

[repository]
ROOT = /data/gitea/data/gitea-repositories

[server]
SSH_DOMAIN = raspberrypi
DOMAIN = raspberrypi
HTTP_PORT = 3000
ROOT_URL = %(PROTOCOL)s://%(DOMAIN)s/gitea/
PROTOCOL = http


It is usually not possible to place any web application under a path prefix, if it is not supported by the application itself. You need to be able to set something like a "base path" in the target application, so redirects and html inline links from the application work correctly.
That's why a service per sub-domain is usually best practice.

I have not been able to get it to work using sub-path. I will use base-path for now. Thanks for the reply.
